# Vue js computed property doesn't fire

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In my data object I've two properties.

```
data() {
    return {
      days: [],
      cdsoFee: '1300'
    };
  },
```

`cdsoFee` is set when the component is mounted. So it's kind of constant.

But the `days` array will change according to the number of days user picks.

In computed properties I did something like this

```
computed: {
    amount() {
      return this.days.length * this.cdsoFee * 100;
    }
  },
```

In my template if I output it like this

```
<template>
    <div>{{amount}}</div>
</template>
```

It works fine.

**But**, in my template I use vue-stripe-checkout

```
<template>
    <div>
        <vue-stripe-checkout
         :amount="amount"
         @done="done"
         @opened="opened"
         @closed="closed"
         @canceled="canceled"
        ></vue-stripe-checkout>
    </div>
</template>
```

Then the amount doesn't come to the component.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you share your <vue-stripe-checkout> component js code?

Comment: @Helpinghand It's an npm pkg https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-stripe-checkout

Comment: How are you populating your days array?

Comment: @Helpinghand it just simple v-model It works well in the template. Only problem is It didn't work with the component. Is this something that component unable to fire the computed?

Comment: Did you try to ask in `<div v-if="amount">` because you maybe sometime get undefined for your amount? @Pathum